# Cleveref: Abbreviate label locally for one reference

Tags: cleveref

how do I make cleveref use an abbreviated version of my reference for just one (a few) references? I usually prefer to write the full label (hence the `noabbrev` option), however I'm currently using some references in table headlines, where I'm running out of space

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   c^2 = a^2 + b^2
   \label{eqn}
\end{equation}

\cref{eqn} shows an interesting result.
\end{document}
```

I'd prefer to locally change the label names (i.e., abbreviate them) for the scope of the table.

I tried calling `\crefname` inside the `table` environment without success.

```
 \begin{table}
 \crefname{equation}{Eq.}{Eqs.} % trying -- unsuccessfully -- to run '\crefname'
 \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        Assumption & \cref{eqn}
    \end{tabular}   
 \end{table}
```

Edit: As pointed out by egreg the solution with `\crefname` inside the table acutally works. I had a typo in my version.

Comment: Works for me. If I add the `table` to your sample document, I get [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5koja.png). Can you please show a full example that doesn't work?

Comment: Well, you're right. I accidentally had `\Cref{eqn}` in the code I copied over. Sorry for the confusion :/

Answer (score 2):

Since you're employing the package option `capitalize` (`capitalise` works too...), you could make use of the fact that the prefix labels generated by `\Cref` are never abbreviated.

Specifically, I suggest that you (a) no longer specify the option `noabbrev`, (b) replace all instances of `\cref` in the document with `\Cref`, and (c) change `\Cref` back to `\cref` if you wish to use abbreviated prefix labels.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref} % note: 'noabbrev' option not specified
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{pyth} c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{triv} 1+1=2 \end{equation}

\Cref{pyth,triv} show that \dots 

\cref{pyth,triv} show that \dots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `hyperref`, you can use the `\hyperref` command and customize on the fly: `\hyperref[eqn]{Eq.~\ref*{eqn}}` in your table entry.

Comment: Not the ideal solution when the type of environments change, but at least a simple hack I'll keep in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @dba Sorry, it should not be `hyperlink` as initially suggested but `\hyperref`. Answer edited.